# Why the animation is showing only on hover and not when leaves?

Tags: css

this is fast, I have a menu that I am trying to animate with the `:hover` event, the menu is on a `navbar` and what I am trying to accomplish is the same behavior as Twitter `navbar`, once you `hover` the links, a border bottom appears, in my case is a `box-shadow` but it doesn't matter. As you see in the example, there is an animation once the user `hover` the links and I want the same animation when the user leaves

See here [my codepen](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/KwoLaQ)

and here my css

```
.capilleira-navbar{
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  a {
    color: getColor(night);
  }
  a:hover, a:focus {
    background: getColor(snow) !important;
    color: red;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px 0px red;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
  img {
    max-width:100px;
    margin-top: -7px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have the transition in the 'a:hover' declaration and not the 'a' declaration. The 'a:hover' is only in effect whilst you are hovering over the element, once you move the mouse off, it doesn't apply anymore, hence why the transition doesn't have any effect then. If you move the transition to the 'a', it will work correctly as shown in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbzXLo)

```css
 a {
    color: getColor(night);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
  a:hover, a:focus {
    background: getColor(snow) !important;
    color: red;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px 0px red;
    margin: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.one {
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.one:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 0px 0px red;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Hover
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the transition in a:hover, a:focus and add this

```
a
{
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```